# Como converter forma de comunicação de Java para Python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Boa Tarde,

Tenho um scrip Java que realiza a comunicação entre a aplicação Java e a controladora MIO Commbox.

Minha dúvida é como converter esse script Java para Python, resumindo, preciso realizar a comunicação via python.

Segue o Script em JAVA:

```
 URLConnection connection =  new URL("http://192.168.0.8:4091/multiio").openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            try( OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()){ 
                output.write("{\"event\": \"read_inputs_outputs\", \"ip\" : \"192.168.0.100\", \"port\" : \"4091\", \"data\" : []}".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }         

BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String text = "";
            String json = "";
            while((text = response.readLine()) != null){
                       json += text;
                        }
```

Preciso escrever esse mesmo código em Python, iniciei a codificação conforme abaixo, mas não estou tendo a resposta

Condificação inicial em Python

```
import socket

sockt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sockt.connect(('192.168.0.8', 4091))
print("Conectado...")

data = bytearray()
payload = '{\"event\":\"read_inputs_outputs\",\"ip\":\"192.168.0.100\",\"port\":\"4091\",\"data\":\"[]\"}'
data = payload.encode('utf-8')

sockt.send(data)

resposta = sockt.recv(4091)
print(resposta)
```

Só imprimi no console "Conectado..." e mais nada aparece no console, não apresenta erros.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que devo fazer? Obrigado!

Comment: A chamada `sockt.send(data)` teve algum retorno?

Comment: Anderson executei print(sockt.send(data)) e retornou o numero 78 que deve ser o tamanho do payload